# How to securely handle authorization session on frontend and backend

Tags: security, oauth

I am building a simple blog webapp and I used Google Oauth2 for log in. After Google Log the user in, it will give me access_token and I will store the user info in React Context, which I think it is creating a authorization session.

My question is, when my frontend is fetching resourses (like blog informations) from the back end. Does it make sense to send the access_token every time to the backend?

Any other security tip would be so useful. Thank you!

Edit 1:
The reason I am using google login is becausse: My backend has a relation table where the primary key is the google user email and the column are things like name, my blogs, etc...

Comment: Does your backend fetch the article from google's API's? Maybe it's better if the access token never gets to the frontend to begin with. If the backend is unrelated to google services, you also don't need to send it there

Comment: @Evert the article does not come from google. As far as passing access_token to the backend. I thought it is a good idea to use things like GoogleIdTokenVerifier to verify the user, and check if the user is actually in the database. Please correct me if this does not make sense security wise

Comment: Ok, consider not sending the access token all to your frontend. Ideally the callback/redirect goes straight to the backend where you check the token. It never has to leave the server if your frontend is not directly talking to google.